# Multi otsu(multi-thresholding) with openCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to carry out multi-thresholding with otsu. The method I am using currently is actually via maximising the between class variance, I have managed to get the same threshold value given as that by the OpenCV library. However, that is just via running otsu method once.

Documentation on how to do multi-level thresholding or rather recursive thresholding is rather limited. Where do I do after obtaining the original otsu's value? Would appreciate some hints, I been playing around with the code, adding one external for loop, but the next value calculated is always 254 for any given image:(

My code if need be:

```
//compute histogram first
cv::Mat imageh; //image edited to grayscale for histogram purpose
//imageh=image; //to delete and uncomment below;
cv::cvtColor(image, imageh, CV_BGR2GRAY);

int histSize[1] = {256}; // number of bins
float hranges[2] = {0.0, 256.0}; // min andax pixel value
const float* ranges[1] = {hranges};
int channels[1] = {0}; // only 1 channel used

cv::MatND hist;
// Compute histogram
calcHist(&imageh, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), hist, 1, histSize, ranges);

IplImage* im = new IplImage(imageh);//assign the image to an IplImage pointer
IplImage* finalIm = cvCreateImage(cvSize(im->width, im->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
double otsuThreshold= cvThreshold(im, finalIm, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY | cv::THRESH_OTSU );

cout<<"opencv otsu gives "<<otsuThreshold<<endl;

int totalNumberOfPixels= imageh.total();
cout<<"total number of Pixels is " <<totalNumberOfPixels<< endl;


float sum = 0;
for (int t=0 ; t<256 ; t++) 
{
    sum += t * hist.at<float>(t);
}
cout<<"sum is "<<sum<<endl;

float sumB = 0; //sum of background
int wB = 0; // weight of background
int wF = 0; //weight of foreground

float varMax = 0;
int threshold = 0;

//run an iteration to find the maximum value of the between class variance(as between class variance shld be maximise)
for (int t=0 ; t<256 ; t++) 
{
       wB += hist.at<float>(t);               // Weight Background
       if (wB == 0) continue;

       wF = totalNumberOfPixels - wB;                 // Weight Foreground
       if (wF == 0) break;

       sumB += (float) (t * hist.at<float>(t));

       float mB = sumB / wB;            // Mean Background
       float mF = (sum - sumB) / wF;    // Mean Foreground

       // Calculate Between Class Variance
       float varBetween = (float)wB * (float)wF * (mB - mF) * (mB - mF);

       // Check if new maximum found
       if (varBetween > varMax) {
          varMax = varBetween;
          threshold = t;
       }
}

       cout<<"threshold value is: "<<threshold;
```

Comment: Otsu does 2-class clustering. Maybe you should try k-means for a 3-class cluster and see what happens?

Comment: One approach to re-apply Otsu on a histogram that has already been thresholded, is to take turn zeroing out the part of histogram that is above, or below, the first Otsu threshold value. This is done by making that part of histogram bins or population counts zero.

Comment: also, please, ditch those IplImages, and use cv::threshold() instead

Comment: maybe you can apply otsu once, then split image in both cluster, apply some white balance normalization on each of them (remember the normalization computation), then apply otsu on each of them. To get the original thresholds, you could undo the normalization computation for that threshold values.

Comment: @scap3y, can you share some links on tat? So that I can have a better understanding. Feel free to put it as answer as I usually upvote all answers to my question unless the answer is totally redundant(like really really bad). Thanks(:

Comment: @berak, agreed. I just used it to find the threshold value, other than that I am all using Mat images, this was insisted by my supervisor to ensure that the values for Mat and IplImage is the same, which is kind of stupid, but he is well, you can say, "old-school"?

Comment: @rwong, that actually produced some results, but it's still different from what I expected. I think I can try work out something from there, and see how it goes. Do repost it as an answer so I can upvote you(not accepted answer tho) as a mean to show my gratitude for you helping.

Answer (score 16):

To extend Otsu's thresholding method to multi-level thresholding the between class variance equation becomes:

[image: multi between class variance]

> Please check out Deng-Yuan Huang, Ta-Wei Lin, Wu-Chih Hu, Automatic
>   Multilevel Thresholding Based on Two-Stage Otsu's Method with Cluster
>   Determination by Valley Estimation, Int. Journal of Innovative
>   Computing, 2011, 7:5631-5644 for more information.
>
> http://www.ijicic.org/ijicic-10-05033.pdf

Here is my C# implementation of Otsu Multi for 2 thresholds:

```
/* Otsu (1979) - multi */

Tuple < int, int > otsuMulti(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //image histogram
    int[] histogram = new int[256];

    //total number of pixels
    int N = 0;

    //accumulate image histogram and total number of pixels
    foreach(int intensity in image.Data) {
        if (intensity != 0) {
            histogram[intensity] += 1;
            N++;
        }
    }

    double W0K, W1K, W2K, M0, M1, M2, currVarB, optimalThresh1, optimalThresh2, maxBetweenVar, M0K, M1K, M2K, MT;

    optimalThresh1 = 0;
    optimalThresh2 = 0;

    W0K = 0;
    W1K = 0;

    M0K = 0;
    M1K = 0;

    MT = 0;
    maxBetweenVar = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k <= 255; k++) {
        MT += k * (histogram[k] / (double) N);
    }


    for (int t1 = 0; t1 <= 255; t1++) {
        W0K += histogram[t1] / (double) N; //Pi
        M0K += t1 * (histogram[t1] / (double) N); //i * Pi
        M0 = M0K / W0K; //(i * Pi)/Pi

        W1K = 0;
        M1K = 0;

        for (int t2 = t1 + 1; t2 <= 255; t2++) {
            W1K += histogram[t2] / (double) N; //Pi
            M1K += t2 * (histogram[t2] / (double) N); //i * Pi
            M1 = M1K / W1K; //(i * Pi)/Pi

            W2K = 1 - (W0K + W1K);
            M2K = MT - (M0K + M1K);

            if (W2K <= 0) break;

            M2 = M2K / W2K;

            currVarB = W0K * (M0 - MT) * (M0 - MT) + W1K * (M1 - MT) * (M1 - MT) + W2K * (M2 - MT) * (M2 - MT);

            if (maxBetweenVar < currVarB) {
                maxBetweenVar = currVarB;
                optimalThresh1 = t1;
                optimalThresh2 = t2;
            }
        }
    }

    return new Tuple(optimalThresh1, optimalThresh2);
}
```

And this is the result I got by thresholding an image scan of soil with the above code:

(T1 = 110, T2 = 147).

[image: original scan]

[image: thresholded scan]

[image: image histogram]

> Otsu's original paper: "Nobuyuki Otsu, A Threshold Selection Method
>   from Gray-Level Histogram, IEEE Transactions on Systems, Man, and
>   Cybernetics, 1979, 9:62-66" also briefly mentions the extension to
>   Multithresholding.
>
> https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/computervision/ECE661.08/OTSU_paper.pdf

Hope this helps.

Comment: `M0 = M0K / W0K; //(i * Pi)/Pi` looks like the sum of t1 to me (= Sum(0, i)). Same for M1.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple general approach for 'n' thresholds in **python** (>3.0) :

```
# developed by- SUJOY KUMAR GOSWAMI
# source paper- https://people.ece.cornell.edu/acharya/papers/mlt_thr_img.pdf

import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

img = cv2.imread('path-to-image')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
a = 0
b = 255
n = 6 # number of thresholds (better choose even value)
k = 0.7 # free variable to take any positive value
T = [] # list which will contain 'n' thresholds

def sujoy(img, a, b):
    if a>b:
        s=-1
        m=-1
        return m,s

    img = np.array(img)
    t1 = (img>=a)
    t2 = (img<=b)
    X = np.multiply(t1,t2)
    Y = np.multiply(img,X)
    s = np.sum(X)
    m = np.sum(Y)/s
    return m,s

for i in range(int(n/2-1)):
    img = np.array(img)
    t1 = (img>=a)
    t2 = (img<=b)
    X = np.multiply(t1,t2)
    Y = np.multiply(img,X)
    mu = np.sum(Y)/np.sum(X)

    Z = Y - mu
    Z = np.multiply(Z,X)
    W = np.multiply(Z,Z)
    sigma = math.sqrt(np.sum(W)/np.sum(X))

    T1 = mu - k*sigma
    T2 = mu + k*sigma

    x, y = sujoy(img, a, T1)
    w, z = sujoy(img, T2, b)

    T.append(x)
    T.append(w)

    a = T1+1
    b = T2-1
    k = k*(i+1)

T1 = mu
T2 = mu+1
x, y = sujoy(img, a, T1)
w, z = sujoy(img, T2, b)    
T.append(x)
T.append(w)
T.sort()
print(T)
```

For full paper and more informations visit [this link](https://people.ece.cornell.edu/acharya/papers/mlt_thr_img.pdf).

Comment: Thresholding here is not based on Otsu's method as was asked in the question.

Comment: Otsu's original method for thresholding produces two clusters only (with one threshold). Here we are trying to find more clusters with multiple thresholds. There are many approaches. This is one.

Answer (score 2):

I've written an example on how otsu thresholding work in python before. You can see the source code here: https://github.com/subokita/Sandbox/blob/master/otsu.py

In the example there's 2 variants, otsu2() which is the optimised version, as seen on Wikipedia page, and otsu() which is more naive implementation based on the algorithm description itself.

If you are okay in reading python codes (in this case, they are pretty simple, almost pseudo code like), you might want to look at otsu() in the example and modify it. Porting it to C++ code is not hard either.

Comment: Yup. I know how otsu thresholding work, my otsu code is actually similar to your otsu2() code, maximising the between class variance. The problem now is how to do a recursive or rather a multi-level thresholding with the value given from the first otsu. But still, thanks for trying, an upvote for you(:

Comment: @rockinfresh this is not an answer to the question, please downvote it instead of upvote. Upvoting is not the same thing as "thanks", and doing it to a wrong answer may misguide future readers.

Answer (score 2):

@Antoni4 gives the best answer in my opinion and it's very straight forward to increase the number of levels.

This is for three-level thresholding:

```
#include "Shadow01-1.cuh"

void multiThresh(double &optimalThresh1, double &optimalThresh2, double &optimalThresh3, cv::Mat &imgHist, cv::Mat &src)
{
double W0K, W1K, W2K, W3K, M0, M1, M2, M3, currVarB, maxBetweenVar, M0K, M1K, M2K, M3K, MT;
unsigned char *histogram = (unsigned char*)(imgHist.data);

int N = src.rows*src.cols;
W0K = 0;
W1K = 0;
M0K = 0;
M1K = 0;
MT = 0;
maxBetweenVar = 0;

for (int k = 0; k <= 255; k++) {
    MT += k * (histogram[k] / (double) N);
}

for (int t1 = 0; t1 <= 255; t1++)
{
    W0K += histogram[t1] / (double) N; //Pi
    M0K += t1 * (histogram[t1] / (double) N); //i * Pi
    M0 = M0K / W0K; //(i * Pi)/Pi

    W1K = 0;
    M1K = 0;

    for (int t2 = t1 + 1; t2 <= 255; t2++)
    {
        W1K += histogram[t2] / (double) N; //Pi
        M1K += t2 * (histogram[t2] / (double) N); //i * Pi
        M1 = M1K / W1K; //(i * Pi)/Pi
        W2K = 1 - (W0K + W1K);
        M2K = MT - (M0K + M1K);

        if (W2K <= 0) break;

        M2 = M2K / W2K;

        W3K = 0;
        M3K = 0;

        for (int t3 = t2 + 1; t3 <= 255; t3++)
        {
            W2K += histogram[t3] / (double) N; //Pi
            M2K += t3 * (histogram[t3] / (double) N); // i*Pi
            M2 = M2K / W2K; //(i*Pi)/Pi
            W3K = 1 - (W1K + W2K);
            M3K = MT - (M1K + M2K);

            M3 = M3K / W3K;
            currVarB = W0K * (M0 - MT) * (M0 - MT) + W1K * (M1 - MT) * (M1 - MT) + W2K * (M2 - MT) * (M2 - MT) + W3K * (M3 - MT) * (M3 - MT);

            if (maxBetweenVar < currVarB)
            {
                maxBetweenVar = currVarB;
                optimalThresh1 = t1;
                optimalThresh2 = t2;
                optimalThresh3 = t3;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Guilherme Silva

Your code has a BUG

You Must Replace:

```
    W3K = 0;
    M3K = 0;
```

with

```
    W2K = 0;
    M2K = 0;
```

and

```
        W3K = 1 - (W1K + W2K);
        M3K = MT - (M1K + M2K);
```

with

```
        W3K = 1 - (W0K + W1K + W2K);
        M3K = MT - (M0K + M1K + M2K);
```

;-)
Regards

EDIT(1):  [Toby Speight]
I discovered this bug by applying the effect to the same picture at different resoultions(Sizes) and seeing that the output results were to much different from each others (Even changing resolution a little bit)

W3K and M3K must be the totals minus the Previous WKs and MKs.
(I thought about this for Code-similarity with the one with one level less)
At the moment due to my lacks of English I cannot explain Better How and Why

To be honest I'm still not 100% sure that this way is correct, even thought from my outputs I could tell that it gives better results. (Even with 1 Level more (5 shades of gray))
You could try yourself ;-)
Sorry

My Outputs:

[3 Thresholds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9zoM.jpg)
[4 Thresholds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f65pi.jpg)

Comment: Some explanation on the changes would probably be useful for others.

Comment: I discovered it looking at output results. I saw that the output results where to much different applying the effect on same picture with different sizes. Basically W3K and M3K must be the totals minus all previous levels W and M.  (sorry for my English)

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful piece of code in this thread. I was looking for a multi-level Otsu implementation for double/float images. So, I tried to generalize example for N-levels with double/float matrix as input. In my code below I am using armadillo library as dependency. But this code can be easily adapted for standard C++ arrays, just replace vec, uvec objects with single dimensional double and integer arrays, mat and umat with two-dimensional. Two other functions from armadillo used here are: vectorise and hist.

```
// Input parameters:
// map - input image (double matrix)
// mask - region of interest to be thresholded
// nBins - number of bins
// nLevels - number of Otsu thresholds

#include <armadillo>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

mat OtsuFilterMulti(mat map, int nBins, int nLevels) {

    mat mapr;   // output thresholded image
    mapr = zeros<mat>(map.n_rows, map.n_cols);

    unsigned int numElem = 0;
    vec threshold = zeros<vec>(nLevels);
    vec q = zeros<vec>(nLevels + 1);
    vec mu = zeros<vec>(nLevels + 1);
    vec muk = zeros<vec>(nLevels + 1);
    uvec binv = zeros<uvec>(nLevels);

    if (nLevels <= 1) return mapr;

    numElem = map.n_rows*map.n_cols;


    uvec histogram = hist(vectorise(map), nBins);

    double maxval = map.max();
    double minval = map.min();
    double odelta = (maxval - abs(minval)) / nBins;     // distance between histogram bins

    vec oval = zeros<vec>(nBins);
    double mt = 0, variance = 0.0, bestVariance = 0.0;

    for (int ii = 0; ii < nBins; ii++) {
        oval(ii) = (double)odelta*ii + (double)odelta*0.5;  // centers of histogram bins
        mt += (double)ii*((double)histogram(ii)) / (double)numElem;
    }

    for (int ii = 0; ii < nLevels; ii++) {
        binv(ii) = ii;
    }

    double sq, smuk;
    int nComb;

    nComb = nCombinations(nBins,nLevels);
    std::vector<bool> v(nBins);
    std::fill(v.begin(), v.begin() + nLevels, true);

    umat ibin = zeros<umat>(nComb, nLevels); // indices from combinations will be stored here

    int cc = 0;
    int ci = 0;
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < nBins; ++i) {
            if(ci==nLevels) ci=0;
                if (v[i]) {
                ibin(cc,ci) = i;
                ci++;
            }
        }
        cc++;
    } while (std::prev_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));

    uvec lastIndex = zeros<uvec>(nLevels);

    // Perform operations on pre-calculated indices
    for (int ii = 0; ii < nComb; ii++) {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < nLevels; jj++) {
            smuk = 0;
            sq = 0;
            if (lastIndex(jj) != ibin(ii, jj) || ii == 0) {
                q(jj) += double(histogram(ibin(ii, jj))) / (double)numElem;
                muk(jj) += ibin(ii, jj)*(double(histogram(ibin(ii, jj)))) / (double)numElem;
                mu(jj) = muk(jj) / q(jj);
                q(jj + 1) = 0.0;
                muk(jj + 1) = 0.0;

                if (jj>0) {
                    for (int kk = 0; kk <= jj; kk++) {
                        sq += q(kk);
                        smuk += muk(kk);
                    }
                    q(jj + 1) = 1 - sq;
                    muk(jj + 1) = mt - smuk;
                    mu(jj + 1) = muk(jj + 1) / q(jj + 1);
                }
                if (jj>0 && jj<(nLevels - 1)) {
                    q(jj + 1) = 0.0;
                    muk(jj + 1) = 0.0;
                }

                lastIndex(jj) = ibin(ii, jj);
            }
        }

        variance = 0.0;
        for (int jj = 0; jj <= nLevels; jj++) {
            variance += q(jj)*(mu(jj) - mt)*(mu(jj) - mt);
        }    

        if (variance > bestVariance) {
            bestVariance = variance;
            for (int jj = 0; jj<nLevels; jj++) {
                threshold(jj) = oval(ibin(ii, jj));
            }
        }    
    }

    cout << "Optimized thresholds: ";
    for (int jj = 0; jj<nLevels; jj++) {
        cout << threshold(jj) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (unsigned int jj = 0; jj<map.n_rows; jj++) {
        for (unsigned int kk = 0; kk<map.n_cols; kk++) {
            for (int ll = 0; ll<nLevels; ll++) {
                if (map(jj, kk) >= threshold(ll)) {
                    mapr(jj, kk) = ll+1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return mapr;
}


int nCombinations(int n, int r) {

    if (r>n) return 0;
    if (r*2 > n) r = n-r;
    if (r == 0) return 1;

    int ret = n;
    for( int i = 2; i <= r; ++i ) {
        ret *= (n-i+1);
        ret /= i;
    }
    return ret;
}
```