# Multi-Level Thresholding. Otsu's Method

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I know this Question is a possible duplicate of [Multi otsu(multi-thresholding) with openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706742/multi-otsumulti-thresholding-with-opencv) as it's very similar. But I don't have enough privileges to make a comment on that so my question is answered.

I'm trying to do THREE level threshold using Otsu's method using OPENCV library. I was following the guides posted by @Antoni4, but it only covers two-level thresholding and I wasn't able to expand it to three level.

I know how to original Otsu's method works, maximizing the between class variance, but how I could add an external (or internal) for-loop for calculating the third level threshold I did not know.

I'm using this code for the two-level thresholding:

```
#include "Shadow01-1.cuh"

void multiThresh(double &optimalThresh1, double &optimalThresh2,double &optimalThresh3, cv::Mat &imgHist, cv::Mat &src) {
double W0K, W1K, W2K, W3K, M0, M1, M2, M3, currVarB, maxBetweenVar, M0K, M1K, M2K, M3K, MT;

unsigned char *histogram = (unsigned char*)(imgHist.data);

int N = src.rows*src.cols;
W0K = 0;
W1K = 0;
M0K = 0;
M1K = 0;
MT = 0;
maxBetweenVar = 0;

for (int k = 0; k <= 255; k++) {
    MT += k * (histogram[k] / (double) N);
}

for (int t1 = 0; t1 <= 255; t1++)
{
    W0K += histogram[t1] / (double) N; //Pi
    M0K += t1 * (histogram[t1] / (double) N); //i * Pi
    M0 = M0K / W0K; //(i * Pi)/Pi

    W1K = 0;
    M1K = 0;

    for (int t2 = t1 + 1; t2 <= 255; t2++)
    {
        W1K += histogram[t2] / (double) N; //Pi
        M1K += t2 * (histogram[t2] / (double) N); //i * Pi
        M1 = M1K / W1K; //(i * Pi)/Pi
        W2K = 1 - (W0K + W1K);
        M2K = MT - (M0K + M1K);

        if (W2K <= 0) break;

        M2 = M2K / W2K;

        currVarB = W0K * (M0 - MT) * (M0 - MT) + W1K * (M1 - MT) * (M1 - MT) + W2K * (M2 - MT) * (M2 - MT);

        if (maxBetweenVar < currVarB)
        {
            maxBetweenVar = currVarB;
            optimalThresh1 = t1;
            optimalThresh2 = t2;
        }

    }
}
```

}

I actually don't what are those two lines:

```
W2K = 1 - (W0K + W1K);
M2K = MT - (M0K + M1K);
```

And how I could expand them for the third threshold.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see you found a solution, but here is some info for the future. Otsus method works best with bimodal distributions. There are two very similar algorithms that work for more than 2 clusters, __Expectation Maximization__, and  __K-means clustering__ both of these methods are in OpenCV. They are natural extensions of Otsus method, Striving to reduce in class variance. Both of these methods can even be used for grouping 2 or more clusters. And in a bimodal case SHOULD produce similar clusters as otsu's method

Comment: @andrew, thank you very much for your comment. I'll definitely look into those and see if they fit better in my application. I'll update the answer as soon as I have more data.

Comment: They aren't exactly the same, but I think they will group your histogram the way you want. Just like Otsu's method, they assume the data is a mixture of Gaussians. Otsu's method finds a threshold between the two classes. Whereas EM or Kmeans will find the actual distributions (mean, variance). Using these properties otsus method calculates the threshold (as seen in you `currVarB` line) so you can compute thresholds if that is what you really want, otherwise use the mean and the variance, depending on your application

Comment: look my comment at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706742/multi-otsumulti-thresholding-with-opencv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706742/multi-otsumulti-thresholding-with-opencv) I found "Silva" algorithm has a bug

Comment: You're right @reexre, thank you very much. I edited the answer.

Comment: See the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706742/multi-otsumulti-thresholding-with-opencv/53883887#53883887

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit] Fixed a bug reported by @reexre
Yeah, never mind.

I implemented a third inner for-loop to add another threshold level and used the following lines as the W3K and M3K, even though I still don't know why they are like this.

```
W3K = 1 - (W1K + W2K);
M3K = MT - (M1K + M2K);
```

It works.

Whole code is, then:

```
#include "Shadow01-1.cuh"

void multiThresh(double &optimalThresh1, double &optimalThresh2, double &optimalThresh3, cv::Mat &imgHist, cv::Mat &src)
{
double W0K, W1K, W2K, W3K, M0, M1, M2, M3, currVarB, maxBetweenVar, M0K, M1K, M2K, M3K, MT;
unsigned char *histogram = (unsigned char*)(imgHist.data);

int N = src.rows*src.cols;
W0K = 0;
W1K = 0;
M0K = 0;
M1K = 0;
MT = 0;
maxBetweenVar = 0;

for (int k = 0; k <= 255; k++) {
    MT += k * (histogram[k] / (double) N);
}

for (int t1 = 0; t1 <= 255; t1++)
{
    W0K += histogram[t1] / (double) N; //Pi
    M0K += t1 * (histogram[t1] / (double) N); //i * Pi
    M0 = M0K / W0K; //(i * Pi)/Pi

    W1K = 0;
    M1K = 0;

    for (int t2 = t1 + 1; t2 <= 255; t2++)
    {
        W1K += histogram[t2] / (double) N; //Pi
        M1K += t2 * (histogram[t2] / (double) N); //i * Pi
        M1 = M1K / W1K; //(i * Pi)/Pi
        W2K = 1 - (W0K + W1K);
        M2K = MT - (M0K + M1K);

        if (W2K <= 0) break;

        M2 = M2K / W2K;

        W2K = 0;
        M2K = 0;

        for (int t3 = t2 + 1; t3 <= 255; t3++)
        {
            W2K += histogram[t3] / (double) N; //Pi
            M2K += t3 * (histogram[t3] / (double) N); // i*Pi
            M2 = M2K / W2K; //(i*Pi)/Pi
            W3K = 1 - (W0K + W1K + W2K);
            M3K = MT - (M0K + M1K + M2K);

            M3 = M3K / W3K;
            currVarB = W0K * (M0 - MT) * (M0 - MT) + W1K * (M1 - MT) * (M1 - MT) + W2K * (M2 - MT) * (M2 - MT) + W3K * (M3 - MT) * (M3 - MT);

            if (maxBetweenVar < currVarB)
            {
                maxBetweenVar = currVarB;
                optimalThresh1 = t1;
                optimalThresh2 = t2;
                optimalThresh3 = t3;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```