# How to automate the low end threshold value in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm using opencv to draw a contour around a very detailed object. I'm able to do it, but different images need different value of low end threshold, and it requires me to experiment with different lower threshold values to get it right. Is there a way I can automate this process?

Currently, I'm finding the threshold like this:

```
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 230, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

The value 230 isn't a constant. It changes for different images.

Comment: Have you tried [Otsu](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html#gsc.tab=0) to estimate the threshold?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work in my case. Unless I'm doing it wrong. I'm trying to detect the cup and the disk of a glaucoma, but using Otsu detects the whole Glaucoma itself.

Comment: Ah, ok makes sense. There is the possibility to do a [multi-level thresholding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706742/multi-otsumulti-thresholding-with-opencv) using Otsu's method. Otherwise, would it be possible for you to share a sample image?

Comment: Sure. [Here's](http://www.medrounds.org/glaucoma-guide/uploaded_images/4-1-734080.jpg) an image showing what a cup looks like (although it's not always so contrasting relative to it's surrounding pixels). [Here's](http://imgur.com/npAlalw) and image where cup detection is quite difficult.

Comment: I assume you cannot change your setup so the area of interest is bigger within the field of view?
Could you at least use raw data so jpg color compression won't hurt you? The image is super noisy.
You should also decrease your exposure time as you are oversaturated in red channel. You have 3 channels in your image but only 2 carry useful information.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting observation is Ostu is able to detect the whole Glaucoma region. Can you try the following steps-

1. extract the region of interest using Ostu(glaucoma region).
2. equalize the contrast in the extracted area, and
3. try Ostu in the new image region.