# I want to improve the accurracy of a binary image

Tags: image-processing, image-thresholding

I used Otsu thresholding to convert a grayscale img to binary. But the accuracy is not much, I want to improve it.

import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def main():

```
imgpath="F:\\Final_Project\\dataset\\im0001.ppm"
img=cv2.imread(imgpath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("Hello",img)
#grayscale
cv2.imshow('Gray image', gray)
cv2.waitKey(5000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
#histogram
plt.hist(gray.ravel(),256,[0,256]);
plt.show()
#otsu thresholding
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow("Otsu",th3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# find otsu's threshold value with OpenCV function
thresh=-1
ret, otsu = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
print( "{} {}".format(thresh,ret) )
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    main()

[this is the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iajfF.jpg)

[this is the binary img I'm getting using my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnQBh.jpg)

[this is the histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVwMu.jpg)

Comment: Your histogram shows that the image has 3 peaks. However, Otsu only works for images with two peaks. You might want to check out how to modify Otsu for multi level thresholding. Some approaches are discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706742/multi-otsumulti-thresholding-with-opencv

Comment: Can you share your original image as well? Looks like a retina scan to me.

Comment: I've added the original image