# Multilevel image threshold

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to obtain an image mask with multiple level of threshold meaning considering on the intensity of the pixels I want to threshold the image - white for brightest regions, grey for slightly less brighter regions and black for relatively darker regions. I have come across various articles about multilevel otsu threshold but I could not find an implementation I could use as reference. Once I have these masks I want to perform the bitwise_and on these mask to retrieve original image area for white and grey regions. Is that possible?
Currently, I am using `ret, thresh_ = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)` for getting the masks.

I have tried to explicitly set the values using if statements.

```
if(thresh_ <=80):
            thresh_ = 0

        elif(thresh_ >80 & thresh_ <=160):
            thresh_ = 150

        else: 
            thresh_ = 255
```

But it didn't work and it gave an error- **The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()**

```
for file in glob.glob(path):
        img = cv2.imread(file)  


        #edge detection
        canny = auto_canny(img)


        #Dilation(Morphological function to increase edge width)
        img_dilate = cv2.dilate(canny, (3,3), iterations = 1)
```

Comment: You could create 3 threshold images using cv2.inrange() for each range you want. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981

Comment: If you search Google, you will find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706742/multi-otsumulti-thresholding-with-opencv and perhaps others. Also from Skimage, see https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_multiotsu.html

Comment: @fmw42 is it available in python?

Comment: Skimage is python compatible

Comment: @fmw42 I tried these approaches but it didn't work for me. Maybe I was doing something wrong. That is why I was explicitly specifying the ranges using if statements.

Comment: Skimage should work. See the example from the link I showed you. If you have trouble, then post your full Python/Skimage code and the image.

Comment: @fmw42 I have tried the skimage approach but I got an error that the depth was zero

Comment: Try the numpy thresholding from j6m8 or show your Skimage code and your image.

Comment: @using the skimage example it is giving an error: ```cannot import name 'threshold_multiotsu' from 'skimage.filters' (C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\filters\__init__.py)```

Comment: It needs Skimage 0.16. Does not exist before that. I cannot test as I am on 0.14 currently.

Comment: @fmw42 ok I'll try it with skimage 0.16 as well. Though j6m8 approach worked for me

Comment: You can get multiple regions by using cv2.kmeans() or np.kmeans. You have to tell it how many colors (regions) you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cv for this might be overkill; you can probably take the image and use numpy-style indexing in order to set your thresholds:

```py
img[img < 80] = 0
img[(img < 160) & (img > 0)] = 150
img[img > 150] = 255
```

(untested)

The reason you're getting the error you're seeing is because comparisons against an array don't work in "vanilla" python; what would you expect the result of `[1, 2, 3] > 2` to return?

But in numpy-flavored Python (which OpenCV uses), the above will return an itemwise comparison of `[False, False, True]`, which is a quality we take advantage of in the code block above.

Comment: should I apply this at the original image?

Comment: Yes — if it is a numpy-array or similar, this code should work directly (and will modify your `img` variable). I can't tell from the code you posted what your `img` variable is set to.

Comment: The image is a numpy array on which I have performed edge detection and dilation.

Answer (score 1):

Using Numpy, the solution can easily be achieved with fast built in functions for a variable number of regions. Assume we are doing grey-level segments. Assuming a list of thresholds T of length k-1 (ex. k = 3 regions, T = [85, 170]).

`import numpy as np`

Digitize will get the bin indices for each element (0...k-1):

`out = np.digitize(image, bins=T)`

Now we map the indices to grayscale color:

`out = out*int(255/(k-1))`